# Inter Channels interference in MIMO system

Tags: digital-communications, mimo

If we have MIMO system with $2$ transmit antennas, ($T_1$ and $T_2$) and $2$ receive antennas ($R_1$ and $R_2$). The received signal of the first received antennas can be explained:

$r_1$ = $h_{11}$$x_1$ + $h_{21}$$x_2$ + $v_1$

where $h_{11}$  denotes the channel between $T_1$  and $R_1$  ,  $h_{21}$, denotes the channel between $T_2$  and $R_1$  , $x_1$ is the signal transmitted from  $T_1$  and $x_2$  is the signal transmitted from $T_2$, and finally  $v_1$  the AWGN on the $R_1$.

The signal received on the second received antennas can also be explained using same way of the above equation.

as I know that $h_{21}$$x_1$ is considered as interference on the first received antenna. Is that right ?

and my question, That interference should be varied in function of distance between the receive antennas, but how can we model that interference? I mean it should be big when the distance between the receive antennas is short and small when the distance is far.  So, how can I model that interference in function of distance too ?

Comment: It's not accurate to say that one term is interference and the other isn't; rather, both $h_{11}x_1$ and $h_{21}x_2$  interfere on each other. The receiver will combine $r_1$ and $r_2$ to obtain good estimates of $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: Can you clarify why do you think that the distance between transmit antennas will affect the interference? In the model you're using, the channels are modeled by $h_{ij}$, and Tx antenna distance does not play a role.

Comment: @MBaz First, I mean that $h_{21}$$x_2$ will be considered as an interference in the first receive antenna and vise versa. Second, I think that distance between transmit antennas affect the interference since the interference will be higher when the antennas are near from each other. It means a correlation will happen between them. Is that right? Moreover, if the antennas are far way from each other, it means that no interference will happen.

Comment: @New_student but that's exactly the wrong way of looking at it: there's no signal "meant" for either antenna with the other interfering. That's really not the case!

Comment: @MarcusMüller  OK .. could you please explain it for me? thanks in advance

Comment: Can't put it better than @MBaz did: the two separate receive signals only emerge by *combining the observations of both receive antennas*. Individually, there's nothing to decode: The information simply isn't there if you're just observing one antenna.

Comment: @New_student Regarding the antennas: it is the _receiver_ antennas which need to be spaced (at least $\lambda/2$ is the usual rule of thumb), not the transmit antennas.

Comment: @MBaz Oh sorry .. I mean the receive antennas !!  I will modify it. Could you please explain the effects of distance between receive antennas and the interference of receives signals ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of increasing the distance between receive antennas is not to reduce the interference; it is to uncorrelate the channels.

In the system you're studying, the signal $x_1$ travels by two paths. One has gain $h_{11}$ and the other has gain $h_{12}$. Both of these gains are random.

A channel is considered bad when the magnitude of its gain, $|h|$, is small. The reason is that, in this case, the signal is likely to be overwhelmed by the noise.

If you had a single receiver antenna, then the probability of having a bad channel is very large. With two receiver antennas, there are two channels; as long as one if them is not bad, the transmitted signal can be recovered. Now, the probability of having *two* bad channels is much less than the probability of having one bad channel. Think of it like this: the probability of rolling two 1s is much less than the probability of rolling one 1.

The above is true as long as the two channels are *uncorrelated*. If the channels are correlated, then they tend to be either both good, or both bad. In this case there is little gain to be obtained by having two antennas.

Imagine that the two receiver antennas are in the same exact place. Obviously, in this case the channels are perfectly correlated. If the antennas are widely separated, then the channels will be completely uncorrelated.

A general rule of thumb is that, in a rich-scattering environment (that is, with lots of signal reflections and scattering), the receiver antennas should be spaced at least $\lambda/2\,\text{m}$, where $\lambda$ is the wavelength of the transmitted signal.

Comment: Please, I have a question regarding to that, .. Is that interference I mentioned above   called also cochannel interference??  I mean in rich multi-path environment.

Comment: Not in the most common usage: normally, co-channel interference results when an unrelated transmitter interferes with another, often because of malfunction.

Comment: Is there a mathematical expression for the co-channel interference or clear explanation I can understand it? thanks in advance

Comment: Id suggest asking a new question.

Comment: I asked new question here https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/70583/what-is-the-co-channel-interference-in-mimo-communication